# How to indicate a range of zoom on the map?

Tags: carto

Basically what I need and I want to know is how you can do to tell the map that respects me a zoom range to display the data, ie, I want to see the map from afar without information, and as the zooming you can go see the information.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Right now, it is not possible in the CartoDB user interface. But it should be in the future. For now, you need to use CartoDB.js in HTML and limit it through your Leaflet or Google Maps code, depending on which you use.

In Leaflet, minZoom and maxZoom are parameters in the map setup,

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-minzoom